# Alternative for "reminds me of"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find an abbreviated statement/word for "reminds me of" in my following sentence:   - this reminds me of my life motto, which is "there but for the grace of God go I".

Comment: "Suggests" might be used, though not ideal in the above context.

Comment: This is ***apropos*** to my life’s motto...

Answer (score 5):

You can say ***[reminiscent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reminiscent)***

> reminding you of someone or something else

[Merriam-Webster]

In your case,

> This is **reminiscent** of my life motto - "there but for the grace of God go I""

Comment: +1 even though to my ears, "reminiscent" is much less personal, and is more a replacement for "reminds **one** of" rather than "reminds **me** of".

Answer (score 4):

"That [brings to mind...](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+to+mind)"

as in

> The film brought to mind the first time I ever climbed a mountain.

Comment: +1. Great minds think alike! Also "that brings me to mind" is another possibility, but it does sound a little old fashioned. Don

Comment: Or “*calls to mind*”

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be difficult to put in a single word. You might be better off with the sentence `This echoes my life's motto, which is "there but for the grace of God go I".`

Or, use `reflect` in place of echo.